# How to check if green color is dominating a picture

Tags: colors, detection

I have couple different pictures and I want to separate them in two different categories, the ones that are landscapes of nature and other ones. The nature ones usually are having dominating green, while the other don't have this characteristic, so I'm trying to find an algorithm that will check if the given picture is having green as a dominating color.

The pictures are given in (R, G, B) format and are of size at most 500 by 500 pixels. I don't know if I can share the picture since I don't own any of the copyrights of the pictures.

I tried to generalize that one pixel is green if G > 200 and R < 100 and B < 100, however in some picture this fails to work, is there better approach for guessing if one pixel is green or not.

Answer (score 0):

Compare G to both R and B.
I'd say you want to see if G is much (up to u how much) greater than both R and B, and at the same time R and B are in range of eachother.

Don't fall for this: G*2 > R+B
If that returns true it dosn't mean the pixel is green, it just means there's a lot of green in it.